# forwarding ping using ip route

Tags: routing, linux-networking, route

I have a Linux setup which consists of two interface.
A local LAN interface and virtual interface.

```
ETH0: 150.10.15.194
PAN0: 192.168.255.209
```

I would like to set rules that route all ICMP echo messages from `ETH0` to `VA0` and vice verca.

I prefer the routing to be static by intertace and not IP. for instance, 
If a packet arrives on `ETH0` and the destination is not local, the packet should be routed to `VA0`.

Same goes for packets that arrive from `VA0` to `ETH0`.

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Firstly, rules are order-dependent, so seeing a few lines of `iptables` is useless; we need the whole output of `iptables -L -n -v`.  Secondly, could you add an example of a client on the 192.168.255` network doing a `ping` to an external client, showing us the failure?

Comment: Iptables is empty before this commands.  I flushed it all

Comment: It'd be better to see than hear that, but OK.  And my latter request above?

Comment: Please see that I changed the question. iptables is not what I need.

Comment: What are the IP networks you have behind those interfaces?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen That's the issue. This is essentially the same network.

Comment: No it is not, there are two separate IP networks here, one starting with `150.` and another with `192.`. What are the complete specifications of those IP networks? And what are `ETH0`, `PAN0` and `VA0` exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to post all your rules to allow us to help you better. Anyway, I can say the following:

1. If you want to allow traffic passing through your firewall, you need to consider `FORWARD` chain. Other chains: `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` are for traffic destined to firewall and originated from firewall respectively.
2. You are allowing `icmp-type 0` which is echo reply. You need to allow echo request also.
3. `FORWARD` default policy will be executed when no matching rule is found. This is also shown using `iptables -L FORWARD -n -v` command.

Comment: Please see that I changed the question. I'm not interested in firewall, but only routing of packets.